# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jMQ (Not found in java.library.path)

Tags: unix, java-native-interface

I have Java Code to load the library of C(32-bit) and I have AIX 7.1 system which has 32 bit java-6 to run the Java Code. But I am getting an following exception.

Code :

```
public class NativeMQChannel {

    static {
        // String jMQlibPath = System.getenv("JMQLIBPATH");
        // String libraryFile = (jMQlibPath != null ? jMQlibPath : "");
        // libraryFile = libraryFile + "jMQ";
        System.loadLibrary("jMQ");
    }

Exception:

Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Session Task-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jMQ (Not found in java.library.path)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1034)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1004)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:507)
    at com.ecs.middleware.channel.NativeMQChannel.<clinit>(NativeMQChannel.java:19)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Please extend you post: Do you actually have a `libjMQ.so` file? Where it is? What is the output of this commands: `ldd /somepath/libjMQ.so; file /somepath/libjMQ.so`? Is property `java.library.path` set accordingly?

Comment: Don't hurry though, take your time.